# draw different type of table

Tags: tables

Hello I want to draw this table in the Latex but as I'm new and try for some hours cannot do it correctly.

[image]

Comment: You should show what you've tried (for hours) rather than just asking to [tag:do-it-for-me]. Is it the placement of the caption? Is the merging of cells horizontally? Vertically? Horizontal alignment of the table columns? What?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope no need of explanations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{some table}
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries}c|*{4}{c|}}\hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\bfseries Wormhole type} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\bfseries 1-hop} &
                                               \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\bfseries 2-hop} \\\cline{2-5}
                       & \textbf{node} & \textbf{true?} & \textbf{node}       & \textbf{true?} \\ \hline
    Hidden         & Normal        & No             & Normal              & No             \\ \hline
    Known Entrance & Malicious     & No             & Normal              & No             \\ \hline
    Known Exit     & Malicious     & Yes            & Normal              & No             \\ \hline
    Exposed        & Malicious     & Yes            & Malicious           & No             \\ \hline
    None           & Malicious     & Yes            & Normal or Malicious & Yes            \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `booktabs` and no vertical rules, this becomes,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{some table}
  \begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}c*{4}{c}}\toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{\bfseries Wormhole type} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries 1-hop} &
                                               \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries 2-hop} \\\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
                       & \textbf{node} & \textbf{true?} & \textbf{node}       & \textbf{true?} \\ \midrule
    Hidden         & Normal        & No             & Normal              & No             \\
    Known Entrance & Malicious     & No             & Normal              & No             \\ 
    Known Exit     & Malicious     & Yes            & Normal              & No             \\ 
    Exposed        & Malicious     & Yes            & Malicious           & No             \\ 
    None           & Malicious     & Yes            & Normal or Malicious & Yes            \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should load `caption` for a correct vertical spacing between caption and table  when caption is *above* table.